# Check if month or day or year is in range of two dates in string format

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-time

[I originally asked this question here with a different use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59867511/check-if-month-or-day-or-year-is-in-range-of-two-dates) but now I realize I could have more cases for this problem.

I have a filter that is a String and can only accept 3 date-formats - `YYYY`, `YYYY-MM`, `YYYY-MM-DD`.

I want to check if the requested String is in the range of two string-valued dates.

Let's say, I have two dates strings which can be in any of the above 3 date-formats

---

**Use case 1**

Start date: `2010-05-15` & end date: `2020-05`.

All the below `requested String` **are In range results**:

`2010`, `2020`, `2010-05`, `2020-05`, `2020-05-22`, `2010-05-15`, `2010-05-22`, `2015-02-25`

All the `requested String` below are **NOT** in range

`2009`, `2021`, `2010-04`, `2020-06`, `2010-05-14`, `2020-06-01`

---

**Use case 2**

Start date: `2010` & end date: `2020-05-15`

All the below values **are In range results**:

`2010`, `2020`, `2010-05`, `2020-05`, `2010-05-22`, `2010-01-01`, `2020-05-15`, `2015-02-25`

All the values below are **NOT** in range

`2009`, `2021`, `2020-06`, `2020-05-16`, `2020-06-01`

---

**Use case 3**

Start date: `NULL` & end date: `2020-05`

All the requested dates which are before `2020-05-31` are In range results:

All the values after `2020-05-31` are NOT in range.

---

**Use case 4**

Start date: `2010-05-15` & end date: `NULL`

All the requested dates which are **after `2010-05-15`** are In range results:

All the values **before `2010-05-15`** are NOT in range.

---

I am using Java time to check if a date is before or after the given dates, but in my case, I have a string as a request date, start date, and end date that could be in any of the 3 date-formats.

I am not sure if this is a valid solution but this is what I am thinking

Simply break all the dates (requested, start, & end) into numbers and compare requested year with years in start & end, if months in requested date is available and also available in the start and end then compare if the month is in range, and same for the dates.

Can someone please help to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have any code for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59884732/5221149) is nice and concise, so you should use it, however it only works because the date formats are simple ISO-8601 texts. If the formats are different, you'd need to parse them, before being able to compare them. Here is a solution that parses the strings, which of course makes the logic more complex.

I would start by creating a helper class:

```
/**
 * Class for storing a {@code Temporal} of varying precision,
 * {@code Year}, {@code YearMonth}, or {@code LocalDate}.
 */
class DynamicTemporal {

    private enum Precision {
        YEAR {
            @Override
            protected int compare(Temporal a, Temporal b) {
                return widen(a).compareTo(widen(b));
            }
            private Year widen(Temporal value) {
                return Year.from(value);
            }
        },
        MONTH {
            @Override
            protected int compare(Temporal a, Temporal b) {
                return widen(a).compareTo(widen(b));
            }
            private YearMonth widen(Temporal value) {
                return YearMonth.from(value);
            }
        },
        DAY {
            @Override
            protected int compare(Temporal a, Temporal b) {
                return widen(a).compareTo(widen(b));
            }
            private LocalDate widen(Temporal value) {
                return (LocalDate) value;
            }
        };
        protected abstract int compare(Temporal a, Temporal b);
    }

    private final Temporal value;
    private final Precision precision;

    public static DynamicTemporal parse(String text) {
        if (text == null || text.equals("NULL"))
            return null;
        if (text.length() >= 10)
            return new DynamicTemporal(LocalDate.parse(text), Precision.DAY);
        if (text.length() >= 7)
            return new DynamicTemporal(YearMonth.parse(text), Precision.MONTH);
        return new DynamicTemporal(Year.parse(text), Precision.YEAR);
    }

    private DynamicTemporal(Temporal value, Precision precision) {
        this.value = value;
        this.precision = precision;
    }

    public int compareTo(DynamicTemporal other) {
        Precision effectivePrecision = (this.precision.compareTo(other.precision) <= 0 ? this.precision : other.precision);
        return effectivePrecision.compare(this.value, other.value);
    }
}
```

Now you can easily implement the `isDateInRange()` method:

```
private static boolean isDateInRange(String start, String end, String date) {
    DynamicTemporal dateTemporal = DynamicTemporal.parse(date);
    DynamicTemporal startTemporal = DynamicTemporal.parse(start);
    DynamicTemporal endTemporal = DynamicTemporal.parse(end);
    if (startTemporal != null && dateTemporal.compareTo(startTemporal) < 0)
        return false; // date is before start
    if (endTemporal != null && dateTemporal.compareTo(endTemporal) > 0)
        return false; // date is after end
    return true;
}
```

*Test (from question)*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("2010-05-15", "2020-05", true, "2010", "2020", "2010-05", "2020-05", "2020-05-22", "2010-05-15", "2010-05-22", "2015-02-25");
    test("2010-05-15", "2020-05", false, "2009", "2021", "2010-04", "2020-06", "2010-05-14", "2020-06-01");

    test("2010", "2020-05-15", true, "2010", "2020", "2010-05", "2020-05", "2010-05-22", "2010-01-01", "2020-05-15", "2015-02-25");
    test("2010", "2020-05-15", false, "2009", "2021", "2020-06", "2020-05-16", "2020-06-01");

    test("NULL", "2020-05", true, "2020-05-31", "2020-05", "2020", "2020-05-30", "2020-04", "2019");
    test("NULL", "2020-05", false, "2020-06-01", "2020-06", "2021", "2020-06-02", "2020-07", "2022");

    test("2010-05-15", "NULL", true, "2010-05-15", "2010-05", "2010", "2010-05-16", "2010-06", "2011");
    test("2010-05-15", "NULL", false, "2010-05-14", "2010-04", "2009", "2010-05-13", "2010-03", "2008");
}
private static void test(String start, String end, boolean expected, String... dates) {
    for (String date : dates) {
        boolean actual = isDateInRange(start, end, date);
        System.out.printf("isDateInRange(%-10s, %-10s, %-10s) = %-5s   %s%n",
                          start, end, date, actual, (actual == expected ? "OK" : "FAILED!"));
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, 2020-05   , 2010      ) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, 2020-05   , 2020      ) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, 2020-05   , 2010-05   ) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, 2020-05   , 2020-05   ) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, 2020-05   , 2020-05-22) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, 2020-05   , 2010-05-15) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, 2020-05   , 2010-05-22) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, 2020-05   , 2015-02-25) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, 2020-05   , 2009      ) = false   OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, 2020-05   , 2021      ) = false   OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, 2020-05   , 2010-04   ) = false   OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, 2020-05   , 2020-06   ) = false   OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, 2020-05   , 2010-05-14) = false   OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, 2020-05   , 2020-06-01) = false   OK
isDateInRange(2010      , 2020-05-15, 2010      ) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010      , 2020-05-15, 2020      ) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010      , 2020-05-15, 2010-05   ) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010      , 2020-05-15, 2020-05   ) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010      , 2020-05-15, 2010-05-22) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010      , 2020-05-15, 2010-01-01) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010      , 2020-05-15, 2020-05-15) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010      , 2020-05-15, 2015-02-25) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010      , 2020-05-15, 2009      ) = false   OK
isDateInRange(2010      , 2020-05-15, 2021      ) = false   OK
isDateInRange(2010      , 2020-05-15, 2020-06   ) = false   OK
isDateInRange(2010      , 2020-05-15, 2020-05-16) = false   OK
isDateInRange(2010      , 2020-05-15, 2020-06-01) = false   OK
isDateInRange(NULL      , 2020-05   , 2020-05-31) = true    OK
isDateInRange(NULL      , 2020-05   , 2020-05   ) = true    OK
isDateInRange(NULL      , 2020-05   , 2020      ) = true    OK
isDateInRange(NULL      , 2020-05   , 2020-05-30) = true    OK
isDateInRange(NULL      , 2020-05   , 2020-04   ) = true    OK
isDateInRange(NULL      , 2020-05   , 2019      ) = true    OK
isDateInRange(NULL      , 2020-05   , 2020-06-01) = false   OK
isDateInRange(NULL      , 2020-05   , 2020-06   ) = false   OK
isDateInRange(NULL      , 2020-05   , 2021      ) = false   OK
isDateInRange(NULL      , 2020-05   , 2020-06-02) = false   OK
isDateInRange(NULL      , 2020-05   , 2020-07   ) = false   OK
isDateInRange(NULL      , 2020-05   , 2022      ) = false   OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, NULL      , 2010-05-15) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, NULL      , 2010-05   ) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, NULL      , 2010      ) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, NULL      , 2010-05-16) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, NULL      , 2010-06   ) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, NULL      , 2011      ) = true    OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, NULL      , 2010-05-14) = false   OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, NULL      , 2010-04   ) = false   OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, NULL      , 2009      ) = false   OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, NULL      , 2010-05-13) = false   OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, NULL      , 2010-03   ) = false   OK
isDateInRange(2010-05-15, NULL      , 2008      ) = false   OK
```

Comment: Thanks, Andreas. Very impressive code. I mentioned earlier "even if that may be the right way to go because we are dealing with dates", so I guess that was a pre-mature statement. I think by going with your solution, it'd allow other modules to use the helper class if the need arrives. I am going to mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: @AMagic As long as you up-vote Basil's answer too, because it is a very *useful* alternative.

Answer (score 3):

## Convert all string inputs to `LocalDate` objects

Stop thinking in strings. The strings are merely for user-interface and for serializing values to storage. When your app is running, you should be performing your logic using objects, *java.time* objects, `LocalDate` ultimately.

Convert all inputs to `LocalDate`.

Check for the length of the input.

```
if( input.length() = 4 ) {…}
```

If the input in 4 characters long, parse as a [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html#atDay(int)). Trap for exception thrown in case faulty input gets past your filter. From the year, get a `LocalDate` by calling [`atDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html#atDay(int)).

```
try{
    Year year = Year.parse( "2020" ) ; 
     LocalDate ld = year.atDay( 1 ) ;
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    …
}
```

If input is seven characters, parse as a `YearMonth`. Form that get a `LocalDate` via the `atDay` method.

```
try{
    YearMonth YearMonth = YearMonth.parse( "2020-05" ) ; 
     LocalDate ld = yearMonth.atDay( 1 ) ;
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    …
}
```

If input is 10 characters, parse as a `LocalDate`.

```
try{
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "2020-05-23" ) ; 
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    …
}
```

Once you have all your `LocalDate` objects in place, compare. Use Half-Open approach consistently when defining your spans of time. The beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

Tip: “not before” is a shorter way of asking “is equal to or later”.

```
( ! target.isBefore( start ) ) && target.isBefore( stop )
```

Comment: *"Once you have all your LocalDate objects in place, compare"* That won't work. Use case 1 includes getting `true` when testing if `"2010"` is in range `"2010-05-15"` to `"2020-05"`. Since you simply convert to date using `atDay(1)`, you'd be comparing if `"2010-01-01"` is in range `"2010-05-15"` to `"2020-05-01"`, which would lead to an *incorrect* `false` result.

Answer (score 3):

As your dates are in the `yyyy-MM-dd` format, you should be able to perform string comparison, making sure that you only compare strings of the same length (to take care of your rules about comparing dates of different lengths):

```
private static boolean isDateInRange(String startDate, String endDate, String date) {
    return (null == startDate || compareDateString(startDate, date) <= 0)
            && (null == endDate || compareDateString(date, endDate) <= 0);
}

private static int compareDateString(String date1, String date2) {
    if (date1.length() == date2.length())
        return date1.compareTo(date2);

    int length = Math.min(date1.length(), date2.length());
    return date1.substring(0, length).compareTo(date2.substring(0, length));
}
```

And you can check in the following way:

```
String startDate = "2010-05-15";
String endDate = "2020-05";
String date = "2020-06";

boolean inRange = isDateInRange(startDate, endDate, date);
```

Comment: Other than not testing `startDate` and `endDate` for value `"NULL"`, that is a good solution.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, I completely forgot about that. Will edit. I took it that OP meant `null`, rather than `"NULL"`, though

Comment: Thank you! An excellent and simple solution for this case. I really didn't want to care about calculating years, yearMonths, localDates and make the code lengthy, even if that may be the right way to go because we are dealing with dates. But I like the simplicity in your code which also works perfect. Thanks again.

Comment: @AMagic With a nice [helper class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59885768/5221149), doing years, yearMonths, and localDates is really not that bad.

Comment: BTW: I tested this answer's code using the test code from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59885768/5221149), and it succeeded, except for the `"NULL"` test cases. Adjust this code to check for `"NULL"` string is of course easy, so it's a great answer.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer makes more sense logically just because all the three fields we are dealing with are dates. So it is better if they are treated as dates.

Answer (score 1):

Convert everything to date ranges. Represent a date range as a half-open interval from start date inclusive to end date *exclusive*. And represent from and to dates as two `LocalDate` objects.

For example, from your use case 1

> Start date: `2010-05-15` & end date: `2020-05`

As a date range this becomes **from 2010-05-15 inclusive to 2020-06-01 exclusive**.

To test whether 2010 is in the range, convert 2010 to the range **from 2010-01-01 to 2011-01-01 exclusive**. Now 2010 is in the range if and only if the two ranges overlap. They do if and only of the first from date is before the second to date *and* the second from date is before the first to date. Use `LocalDate.isBefore()`. We need “strictly before”, and this method gives us exactly that. Since 2010-05-15 is before 2011-01-01 *and* 2010-01-01 is before 2020-06-01, the ranges overlap, so we conclude that 2010 is in the range.

Another example from case 1, to test whether 2010-05-14 is in the same range, convert it to a range **from 2010-05-14 to 2010-05-15 (exclusive)**. See if 2010-05-15 is before 2010-05-15 *and* 2010-05-14 is before 2020-06-01. Already the first half is false, so we conclude that the date is not in the range.

Implementation note: I might use this formatter for parsing all of your strings:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu[-MM[-dd]]");
```

You may use the `parseBest` method of this formatter to obtain either a `LocalDate`, a `YearMonth` or a `Year` from any of the strings you have mentioned. In each case you can convert from there.

**Link:** [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure if this is a valid solution but this is what I am
>   thinking
>
> Simply break all the dates (requested, start, & end) into numbers and
>   compare requested year with years in start & end, if months in
>   requested date is available and also available in the start and end
>   then compare if the month is in range, and same for the dates.

Yes, your approach is valid. The classes from java.time don’t offer perfect support for it, but with the low-level `TemporalAccessor` interface there is a way through:

```
class IsInRangeWithMissingFields {

    @Test
    void useCase1() {
        assertTrue(isInRange("2010-05-15", "2020-05", "2010"));
        assertTrue(isInRange("2010-05-15", "2020-05", "2020"));
        assertTrue(isInRange("2010-05-15", "2020-05", "2010-05"));
        assertTrue(isInRange("2010-05-15", "2020-05", "2020-05"));
        assertTrue(isInRange("2010-05-15", "2020-05", "2020-05-22"));
        assertTrue(isInRange("2010-05-15", "2020-05", "2010-05-15"));
        assertTrue(isInRange("2010-05-15", "2020-05", "2010-05-22"));
        assertTrue(isInRange("2010-05-15", "2020-05", "2015-02-25"));
        assertFalse(isInRange("2010-05-15", "2020-05", "2009"));
        assertFalse(isInRange("2010-05-15", "2020-05", "2021"));
        assertFalse(isInRange("2010-05-15", "2020-05", "2010-04"));
        assertFalse(isInRange("2010-05-15", "2020-05", "2020-06"));
        assertFalse(isInRange("2010-05-15", "2020-05", "2010-05-14"));
        assertFalse(isInRange("2010-05-15", "2020-05", "2020-06-01"));
    }

    @Test
    void useCase2() {
        assertTrue(isInRange("2010", "2020-05-15", "2010"));
        assertTrue(isInRange("2010", "2020-05-15", "2020"));
        assertTrue(isInRange("2010", "2020-05-15", "2010-05"));
        assertTrue(isInRange("2010", "2020-05-15", "2020-05"));
        assertTrue(isInRange("2010", "2020-05-15", "2010-05-22"));
        assertTrue(isInRange("2010", "2020-05-15", "2010-01-01"));
        assertTrue(isInRange("2010", "2020-05-15", "2020-05-15"));
        assertTrue(isInRange("2010", "2020-05-15", "2015-02-25"));
        assertFalse(isInRange("2010", "2020-05-15", "2009"));
        assertFalse(isInRange("2010", "2020-05-15", "2021"));
        assertFalse(isInRange("2010", "2020-05-15", "2020-06"));
        assertFalse(isInRange("2010", "2020-05-15", "2020-05-16"));
        assertFalse(isInRange("2010", "2020-05-15", "2020-06-01"));
    }

    @Test
    void useCase3() {
        assertTrue(isInRange(null, "2020-05", "2020-05-31"));
        assertFalse(isInRange(null, "2020-05", "2020-06-01"));
    }

    @Test
    void useCase4() {
        assertTrue(isInRange("2010-05-15", null, "2010-05-15"));
        assertFalse(isInRange("2010-05-15", null, "2010-05-14"));
    }

    private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu[-MM[-dd]]");

    public static boolean isInRange(String startStr, String endStr, String requestStr) {
        TemporalAccessor request = formatter.parse(requestStr);

        // is request before start?
        if (startStr != null) {
            TemporalAccessor start = formatter.parse(startStr);
            if (request.get(ChronoField.YEAR)
                    < start.get(ChronoField.YEAR)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (request.get(ChronoField.YEAR)
                    == start.get(ChronoField.YEAR)) {
                if (request.isSupported(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)
                        && start.isSupported(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)) {
                    if (request.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)
                            < start.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (request.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)
                            == start.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)) {
                        if (request.isSupported(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                                && start.isSupported(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
                            if (request.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                                    < start.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // is request after end?
        if (endStr != null) {
            TemporalAccessor end = formatter.parse(endStr);
            if (request.get(ChronoField.YEAR) > end.get(ChronoField.YEAR)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (request.get(ChronoField.YEAR) == end.get(ChronoField.YEAR)) {
                if (request.isSupported(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)
                        && end.isSupported(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)) {
                    if (request.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)
                            > end.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (request.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)
                            == end.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)) {
                        if (request.isSupported(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                                && end.isSupported(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
                            if (request.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                                    > end.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

This unit test runs green-barred on my computer.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Date min, max;   // assume these are set to something
    Date d;          // the date in question

   return d.after(min) && d.before(max);
```

Comment: All three dates in question are String type with `YYYY`, `YYYY-MM`, & `YYYY-MM-DD` formats. I can't really parse these into date consistently. :(

Comment: How does that test true for inputs `d = 2010, min = 2010-05-15, max = 2020-05`?

Comment: d takes a higher preference, if d is only a year, then min=2010-05-15 is included in it and accepted in range.